# How can I speed up gulp?

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-spark

On a vanilla Laravel Spark install, it takes me about 20 seconds to run gulp. Here's my log:

> [15:05:48] Starting 'all'...
>
> [15:05:48] Starting 'less'...
>
> [15:05:53] Finished 'less' after 4.74 s
>
> [15:05:53] Starting 'webpack'...
>
> [15:05:58]
>
> [15:05:58] Finished 'webpack' after 5.28 s
>
> [15:05:58] Starting 'copy'...
>
> [15:05:59] Finished 'copy' after 486 ms
>
> [15:05:59] Starting 'copy'...
>
> [15:05:59] Finished 'copy' after 17 ms
>
> [15:05:59] Starting 'less'...
>
> [15:05:59] Finished 'less' after 159 ms
>
> [15:05:59] Starting 'version'...
>
> [15:05:59] Finished 'version' after 517 ms
>
> [15:05:59] Finished 'all' after 11 s
>
> [15:05:59] Starting 'default'...

My gulpfile:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var path = require('path');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
        .webpack('app.js', null, null, {
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js'),
                    'node_modules'
                ]
            }
        })
        .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js', 'public/js/sweetalert.min.js')
        .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css', 'public/css/sweetalert.css');

    mix.less('/brand/brand.less');
    
    mix.version(['css/brand.css', 'css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
```

I'm using the latest version of gulp and gulp CLI on a Mac Mini running valet. What can I do to make this run faster? 20 seconds seems excessive.

Comment: Maybe include your gulpfile.js

Comment: Added. For the people voting to close, this is where Gulp's official docs require that support questions get asked. Is there a more appropriate stackexchange for this?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I have no idea why people are down voting either.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't imply that it did, and I asked if there was a more appropriate stackexchange. The setups are vanilla so I'm not sure that codereview would be appropriate either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try is to deactivate sourcemaps generation:

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
```

Second you can deactivate versioning in development mode, your app should work the same without any change:

```
if (elixir.config.production) {
  mix.version(['css/brand.css', 'css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
}
```